# Store is not defined in an Actions

Tags: reactjs

So, I want to use stored data from another store called `UserStore`. The Actions is `FavoriteActions` with `FavoriteStore`. Where I call `UserStore.getState()` inside one of the method on `FavoriteActions`, it says `UserStore.getState is not a function`. Strange, I have a similar code using `UserStore` and it works. I already require it on top of the file.

Here is the file.

```
var alt = require('../utils/alt');

var UserStore = require('../stores/UserStore');

var FavoriteActions = alt.createActions({

  favorite: function(variant_id, list_id) {
    this.dispatch();
    # THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    var token = UserStore.getState().current_user.token;
    var headers = { 'X-Spree-Token': token };
    var params = {
      variant_id: variant_id
    };

    axios.get(base_url + '/shopping_lists/' + list_id + '/items', {
      headers: headers,
      params: params
    })
    .then(FavoriteActions.updateFavorite)
    .catch(FavoriteActions.favoritesFailed);
  },

  updateFavorite: function(result) {
    this.dispatch(result);
  },

  updateFavoriteId: function(list_id) {
    this.dispatch(list_id);
  },

  updateFavorites: function(result) {
    this.dispatch(result);
  },

  favoritesFailed: function(error_message) {
    this.dispatch(error_message);
  },
});

module.exports = FavoriteActions;
```

I'm using [alt](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt). This is the `UserStore` file.

```
var alt = require('../utils/alt');
var UserActions = require('../actions/UserActions');

var UserStore = alt.createStore({
  displayName: 'UserStore',

  bindListeners: {
    login: UserActions.LOGIN,
    logout: UserActions.LOGOUT,
    updateUser: UserActions.UPDATE_USER,
    clearUser: UserActions.CLEAR_USER,
    loginFailed: UserActions.LOGIN_FAILED
  },

  state: {
    current_user: null,
    errorMessage: null,
    loading: false
  },

  login: function() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
  },

  updateUser: function(user) {
    this.setState({
      current_user: user,
      loading: false
    });
  },

  logout: function() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
  },

  clearUser: function() {
    this.setState({
      current_user: null,
      loading: false
    });

  // FIXME: Unset user session
  },

  loginFailed: function(errorMessage) {
    this.setState({
      errorMessage: errorMessage,
      loading: false
    });
  }
});

module.exports = UserStore;
```

Comment: What *is* UserStore.getState if you log it?

Comment: it is `undefined`. The UserStore itself is like an empty object `Object {}`

Comment: And you're sure the path to UserStore is correct in your `require()` statement?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure because I'm using the same `require()` path with the other Actions that use `UserStore`

Comment: Can you also post your UserStore file? It seems very weird if UserStore is empty, even immediately after your `require()` statement? What module bundler do you use? Webpack? Browserify?

Comment: I already put the file. Yes, I found it very strange because it only happens on this actions. I use Browserify.

Comment: even though we only see a glimpse of your project here, is it possible you have a circular reference situation?  That might explain the empty object representation on UserStore